# deps not allowed without srcs - move to runtime deps?

Tags: bazel

I am migrating from a Maven project to a Bazel project. I can generate jar files to be used as dependencies when I want to generate java libraries. When I use them in my build file as `deps` it gives me the following error:

> deps not allowed without srcs - move to runtime deps?

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're making a java_binary, you can specify [runtime_deps](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary.runtime_deps) and a [main_class](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary.main_class).

See: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after having refactored away all code usages of the dependencies listed inside the `BUILD` file's `deps = [ ... ]`. The fix was to remove the entire `deps` section.